# Using zsh, rvm, and iterm2 not reusing my current directory when opening new tab

Tags: rvm, zsh, iterm2

I'm using rvm, zsh and iterm2 on development. When I'm going to the directory of my project using iterm2 and then open new tab why is it that my new tab always redirect me to the root directory? I change the preferences of my iterm2 to reuse previous tab directory.

[iterm2 screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/0z0u311H100a/Image%202014-05-07%20at%2011.06.26%20AM.png)

I want to reuse my previous working directory when opening new tab.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just reinstalled my bash and zsh. First I followed this

http://vigodome.com/blog/2011/12/30/change-default-shell/

and reinstall zsh